# Splitting a column into a row and extracting selective data in unix

Tags: unix, awk, split

I have an requirement wherin ,there is a raw data file with one column(which has different records each record starts with VMEMBER NAME) in a fixed format and i need to extract each record
and display only few fields it in a tabular format

Input file:

```
VMEMBER NAME ABCD
V***** dssdsdsdsdddassdas
VUSER
VSESSION
VPROF QFUSER
VACB SDDSDASD
VAPPLID USAS
VAPPLID ZXCV
VAPPLID TYU
VMEMBER NAME EFGH
V***** dssdsdsdsdddassdas
VUSER asddds
VSESSION ssdsasad
VPROF  GFUSER
VACB SDDSDASD
VAPPLID USAS
VAPPLID ASDF
VAPPLID ERTT
```

Output:

```
VMEMBER NAME  VPROF     VAPPLID
ABCD         QFUSER     USAS,ZXCV,TYU
EFGH         GFUSER     USAS,ASDF,ERTT
```

I have tried this using awk and the last part of VAPPLID is working (group by)
But i am not able to get the output with all three columns mentioned above

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/160400-transpose-column-row.html

Could you please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "VMEMBER NAME\tVPROF\t\tVAPPLID"}
     $1=="VMEMBER" {OFS=""; printf("%s%s\t\t",x,$3)}
     $1=="VPROF"   {printf("%s\t\t",$2)}
     $1=="VAPPLID" {x=RS; printf("%s%s",OFS,$2); OFS=","}
     END{print ""}' file
```

Output:

```
VMEMBER NAME    VPROF           VAPPLID
ABCD            QFUSER          USAS,ZXCV,TYU
EFGH            GFUSER          USAS,ASDF,ERTT
```

`RS` contains by default a newline.

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, **OFS**, **RS**, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)